# Производная-непроизводная основа

Tags: словообразование

Вот есть слова,по которым понятно от каких слов они произошли, но с другой стороны они ведь только от них получили своё название, а после стали самостоятельными. Как земляника от земля, столовая от стол, и я так понял, что вторые слова считаются производными от первых, но как-то это не так, они же только произошли от них.
Ведь земляной, земельный, земной относятся к земле, а земляника, хоть и производное от слова земля, но относится уже к растению. 
Получается в словах: медведь, малина тоже можно сказать, что их основа производная от слов мёд и мал?

Answer (score 3):

Все что касается слова "малина", то этимология ее еще не ясна. Некоторые лингвисты полагают, что слово связано с корнем "мал-": малиновая ягода состоит из множество "малых" ягодок-зернышек. Другие полагают, что слово происходит от древнего индоевропейского корня: "синий" или "черный"( греческое "м**е**лас" - черный), и считают, что ягода получила свое название за свой темно-красный, "малиновый" цвет.В слове же медведь два корня: "мед" и "ед" - "еда". Буквально: "медоед".

Answer (score 2):

"...Как земляника от земля, столовая от стол, и я так понял, что вторые слова считаются производными от первых, но как-то это не так, они же только произошли от них..."
А в чём неясность? Слова "земляника" и "столовая" действительно произошли от слов "земля" и "стол", но стали САМОСТОЯТЕЛЬНЫМИ словами. Вот, к примеру, Вы, AMK1112, "произошли" от Ваших родителей; но Вы не Ваши родители, а самостоятельный человек.)